# How to use LIKE in WHERE clause in SwifQL

Tags: vapor, vapor-fluent

how can I add WHERE x LIKE $xyz to query builder?

i started with

```
let searchQuery = try? request.query.get(String.self, at: "s")
...
query.where(\Talk.title, SwifQL.like(searchQuery))
```

but what next I want to search for case insensitive string I have error:

`[ ERROR ] PostgreSQLError.server.error.scanner_yyerror: GET /testroute?s=Swift syntax error at or near "$8" (ErrorMiddleware.swift:26)`

Answer (score 5):

solution:

```swift
query.where((\Talk.title).iLike("%\(searchQuery ?? "x")%"))
```